# Setup own Openlayers Proxyhost

Tags: javascript, proxy, openlayers, wms

I have seen some example related to WMS Get Feature Info like :

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html

In this example they are using

```
 OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
```

My question is :

How we can setup our own proxthost for our geoserver layers?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From [Frequently Asked Questions about the OpenLayers project](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost).

To use a cgi proxy you can use the example proxy.cgi either from [Trac](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi) or [GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/examples/proxy.cgi).  You probably should use the GitHub link but I have included the Trac link for completeness.

For the standard Apache configuration, you would place proxy.cgi into your /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory.

You don't have to use CGI proxy to handle sending trusted requests across domains. On a machine using IIS to serve the OpenLayers map pages, I have used Application Request Routing rather than a CGI script to forward http requests to a trusted GeoServer.